# using awk in a bash script with if

Tags: bash, scripting, awk

I'm doing a script in which I need to test a string and based on its result I'll decide if I go further or not.

The command below works fine (if the string starts with "Clean" it will print 1, otherwise 0).

```
echo | awk ' {print index("'"${task}"'", "Clean")}'
```

What I'm trying to do is to use the AWK with IF in a BASH script. Based on this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/58768/bash-script-that-tests-for-ip) I did the following:

```
idx=$(awk '{print index("'"${task}"'", "Clean")}')
echo $idx
if [ "$idx" == "0" ]; then
   echo hello
fi
```

As I said, when I run the script it prints "0", but the second "echo" doesn't print anything, and of course the if doesn't works either.

Can anyone help me?

TIA,

Bob

Comment: Thanks womble. I wan't aware that we could use regex directly in the IF statment. It worked. I found good references on the following links: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver3.html#REGEXMATCHREF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Awk is the wrong solution here.  How about:

```
if [[ "$task" =~ ^Clean ]]; then
  echo hello
fi
```

There's also a sneaky substitution method:

```
if [ "${task/#Clean/}" != "$task" ]; then
  echo hello
fi
```

But I find that to be far less readable.

---

Chris reckons case is tidier... let's try that out:

```
case $task in
  Clean*)
    echo hello
    ;;
esac
```

My aesthetic sense says "hell no with bells on", and fiddling with the formatting (`Clean*) echo hello;;` or similar) won't help much, IMAO.  If you want a conditional, use an `if`, I say.

Comment: You can use case for stuff like this; it's typically quite a bit tidier.

Comment: The nice thing about case statements is that they eliminate great big piles of if ; then ; elif ; then ; elif ; then ; else; fi structures, and they have better regular expression matching than test.

Comment: Well, when we get to having lots of if/elif blocks *involving the same variable*, we can switch to using a case statement.  Also, case uses pathname expansion (roughly, globbing), whereas `[[ =~` uses *actual* regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Womble's answer is probably what I would go for, but you can also use grep:

```
if echo cleanarf | grep -qi '^clean'; then 
   echo foo
fi
```

Drop the `i` switch to grep if you want it case sensitive (or if you do not want it case insensitive :-p ).

Comment: This is less readable, IMAO, and slower because it involves spawning a separate process.

Comment: Agreed, that is why I said I would opt for your answer :-P But options are good.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you use `echo` to provide `awk` with a file (`stdin`), but in your script, there is no file for `awk` to process and it "hangs" waiting for input. You could use `echo` in your variable assignment in the `$()`, but I prefer to use `/dev/null` for this purpose (i.e. when there's no actual file to process).

In order to avoid awkward quoting, you can use variable passing with the `-v` option to provide Bash variables to an `awk` script.

You should find that this works:

```
idx=$(awk -v task="$task" '{print index(task, "Clean")}' /dev/null)
echo $idx
if [ "$idx" == "0" ]; then
   echo hello
fi
```

You should probably use **womble**'s suggestion, though, since it doesn't require spawning a separate process.